# slide down and delay in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an hidden div slide down on the click of a button and also wait for about five seconds before sliding back up. I've tried the delay() but i don't know if i'm not implementing it right. Also and when the div isn't hidden it just displays the image.
I have this so far http://jsfiddle.net/2sMFn/3/ 
Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: It should be slideUp not SlideUp...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you have to change this:

```
$this.delay(5000).SlideUp(6000);
```

to this

```
$this.delay(5000).slideUp(6000);
```

as it's slideUp whithout the capitol "S" ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sMFn/8/)

Comment: You need to explain the problem, as we sure as h3ll don't see it, the fiddle seems to be working ?

Comment: haha sorry,it was indeed working, it just wasn't working when i implemented it but it is now :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$this.delay(5000).slideUp(6000);
```

Answer (score 1):

following is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2sMFn/17/): http://jsfiddle.net/2sMFn/19/

function name is 'slideUp()' instead of 'SlideUp'. So use this :

```
 $this.delay(5000).slideUp(6000);
​
```