# How can I get jQuery to wait a second before closing my sliding menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

I tried using setTimeout but it just broke things. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(400);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp(400);
        }
    );
}); // end ready
```

I'd like a 1 second pause before the .slideUp. Help?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code

Comment: Guess, this works
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111977/slide-down-and-delay-in-jquery

Comment: $(this).children('.sub-menu').delay(1000).slideUp(400);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `delay`:

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').delay(1000).slideDown(400);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').delay(1000).slideUp(400);
        }
    );
}); // end ready
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score -1):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp(400);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you not even read the OPs question? He said he already tried that.

Comment: I know that, but the OP does not include his setTimeout version. And my solution really work: http://jsfiddle.net/aqfhxuo6/